# How to load a Javascript file within another Javascript file and execute file 2 before file 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a jQuery plugin, say `jquery.plugin.js`. I want to use this plugin on a large number of sites.

What I want to do is to write a piece of js code at the top of `jquery.plugin.js` which will load the `jquery.main.js` and execute it so that `$` is available to be used in `jquery.plugin.js`.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe take a look at requirejs http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: Why not just include the jquery.main.js above the plugin in the HTML?

Comment: @tjameson because I will be using this plugin on large no. of sites which may or may not have main jquery js loaded. I just want to test if jquery is not defined then load it & execute it so that $ is available to be used in jquery plugin

Comment: Maybe because he doesn't have full access to the HTML?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want to do is create a new tag in js

```
script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'URL-TO-JQUERY';
```

And then append that element before the first tag.

```
document.body.insertBefore(document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0], script);
```

This will most probably work as the script is inserted before any other js. (except in the head)

Yes, just a interval that checks if jQuery exists:

```
interval = setInterval(check, 100);
function check(){
  if($.version){
    // Exec script
  }
}
```

Comment: Some care would have to be taken here, as the current context won't be interrupted to load/execute the new script. There would have to be some kind of setTimeout or other asynchronous request. He'd probably have to use a setInterval(function () { if ($) doPlugin(); }) or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

This page may be useful for you

http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ajaxq/

with this script you can use files sequentially

Answer (score 0):

Just include the `jquery.main.js` above the `jquery.plugin.js`. It should work if you place the script tags in this order.

```
<script src="jquery.main.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
```

If you do not have full control over the html or if jQuery might be loaded from other places also, do this to check if it is loaded or not, and load only if needed.

Load from google

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>');
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript">');
        google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
    document.write('</script>');
}
```

Load from same server

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {  
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/jquery.min.js"></script>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works only if jQuery is loaded already,

```
$.when($.getScript("path_to_script")).then(function() {

   alert("loaded");
})​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fLuDd/

### Edit

```
var fileref = document.createElement('script')
fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript")
fileref.setAttribute("src", 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js')
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)


var t = setInterval(function() {
    if (typeof(jQuery) == 'function') {
        alert("jquery loaded");
        clearInterval(t);
    }
}, 2000);​
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/fLuDd/1/

Answer (score 0):

There are some AMD packages that do what you want, like requirejs, but... you'll have to load them first!

You could use a polling technique (load jQuery dynamically and poll until $ exists), not very elegant or efficient.

You could also attach an onload event handler to the dynamic jQuery script, which will trigger your plugin after loading jQuery. Of course such event handlers have cross-browser compatibility issues, so it's easier to write them... with jQuery.

Bottom line: it's a lot of trouble and you're usually better off just writing two script tags.

P.S.: Some of the above techniques are explained in this article:
http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/12/27/coupling-async-scripts/